# How to show that $\phi(z, \varphi):=(f(z)\cos{(\varphi)}, f(z)\sin{(\varphi)}, z)$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, measure-theory, manifolds

Let $U$ be open and $M_{f}:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^{3}: x^{2}+y^{2}=f(z)^{2}\}$ and define:

$\phi: U \times ]-\pi,\pi[ \to M_{f}\setminus V$ where 
$\phi(z, \varphi):=(f(z)\cos{(\varphi)}, f(z)\sin{(\varphi)}, z)$

and $f \in C^{1}(U)$ is strictly positive on $U$ and $V=M_{f}\setminus\phi(U \times ]-\pi,\pi[)$

Show that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

My idea:

$\phi$ is by definition bijective and continuously differentiable as $f \in C^{1}(U)$ thus all that is left to be shown is that $\phi^{-1}$ is indeed continuous. And this is where I am stuck. The preimage and image of $\phi$ do not have the same dimension so looking at the invertability of $D \phi$ does not make sense.

And if I take any arbitrary points in $M_{f}\setminus V$, say $(a,b,c)$ then I know that there exists $\varphi\in]-\pi,\pi[$ and $z \in U$so that $(a,b,c)=(f(z)\cos{(\varphi)},f(z)\sin{(\varphi)},z)$ but now how do I get to the preimage?

**My attempt:**

Since we have an arbitrary $(a,b,c) \in M_{f}\setminus V$, we know that 
there exists $\varphi\in]-\pi,\pi[$ and $z \in U$so that $(a,b,c)=(f(z)\cos{(\varphi)},f(z)\sin{(\varphi)},z)$.

Define $\phi^{-1}(a,b,c)=(\cos^{-1}({\frac{a}{f(c)})},c)$, note that $f(c) > 0$ from above. and therefore $\phi^{-1}(a,b,c)$ is partially differentiable and thereby continuous. Is this correct?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your use of arccosine can only tell you about points in the $ab$-plane in quadrants I and II.  If you switch to arcsine, it can only tell you about points in quadrants I and IV.  You might benefit from thinking about why [atan2()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) exists.  (The definition given there  using the tangent half-angle formula might be of immediate interest.)

Also, while the image of $\phi$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the image is just a 2-manifold, so the preimage and image of $\phi$ are both 2-dimensional.